# ListViewのチェックボックスを外した時のイベントは取得できない、で正しいでしょうか？

Tags: vba

ListViewのチェックボックスを外した時のイベントは取得できない、で正しいでしょうか？ItemCheckはチェックを付けた時だけしか感知しませんでした。

やりたいことは、チェックボックスのON/OFFによって、変更があった行だけの情報を内部データに更新したいと思っています。

ItemClickというイベントだと、チェックボックスをチェックボックス以外の行の部分をクリックすると感知しますが、チェックボックスに対するクリック（チェックした時/チェックを外した時）は感知しません。

最終手段として考えているのが、Clickイベントというのがありますが、これを使ってListViewに対するクリックがあったら、ListView内の全情報を内部データに更新するという方法しかないのでしょうか？

Comment: 「正しい」ことにこだわるのなら、おそらくそのListViewコントロールはVB6.0のコンポーネントでしょうから、「既に新規開発用に使うためのサポート期間は終了している」ので、「コントロール自身を使わない」ことが「正しい」と思われます。[Visual Basic 6.0 には、どのようなライフサイクル ポリシーが適用されますか?](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/lifecycle/faq/developer-tools#smallwhat-lifecycle-policy-does-visual-basic-60-followsmall), [ListViewコントロールの使い方、イベント一覧、エラー](https://excwlvba.blogspot.com/2013/05/listview.html), [Offce 2019 VBA 64 bit版のオフィスで使えないはずのListviewやTreeviewが限定的に使える件(追記)](https://qiita.com/Q11Q/items/b4f8d50e760d114b21fd)

Comment: VBA側の改造量もそれなりにありそうですが、この辺の記事を使って同等機能を.NETで自作する手も考えられます。[VB.NETライブラリのコントロールをVBAツールボックスに表示させるには](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ja-JP/f2fcc590-d04a-4fda-8993-f03a054c960e/vbnetvba?forum=vbgeneralja), [C#で書いたライブラリをExcel VBAから使用する（COMコンポーネント）](https://www.shujima.work/entry/2020/05/10/162356), [ListView.ItemCheck イベント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.itemcheck?view=net-5.0), [CheckedListBox.ItemCheck イベント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck?view=net-5.0)

Comment: 再度確認しましたら、ItemClickイベントはON/OFFの両方の場合でイベントが発生していました。ですので、ItemClickイベントで実装できました。